# VB6 string to char* conversion: avoid null character

Tags: c, string, winapi, vb6

I'm actually using the `WideCharToMultiByte` function to convert a VB6 string to a C string (`char *` ). Everything works fine, except that if the source string contains a null character then the C string is truncated.

For exmaple:

```
vbString = "Hello " & Chr(0) & " world!"
```

The resulting C string is `Hello \0`. I can't find any option in the function documentation to avoid this behavior.

Any ideas?

Comment: A "C string" isn't necessarily ANSI or ASCII, many compilers support UTF-16LE as well.  But since a NUL always terminates one either way, no, there isn't anything you can do.  Unless the code written in C uses byte/char array operations instead of "string" operations you can't have a NUL character.  Perhaps there are BSTR functions you can use instad?

Comment: ...and even if you could, most things which would use the string would see the embedded NUL as the end of the string and ignore the rest

Comment: @Bob77 You're right guys. But I solved this by iterating into the VB6 string characters and manually replacing `\0` whith a single space. Thanks!

Comment: @cdonts: you don't need to resort to that.

Answer (score 3):

Truncation only happens if you are treating the VB string as null-terminated.  `WideCharToMultiByte()` lets you specify the actual string length so nulls are ignored.  VB strings are COM `BSTR` strings, so you can use `SysStringLen()` to get the full length of the VB string and pass that to `WideCharToMultiByte()`.

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 string is actually a BSTR that can be manipulated using BSTR functions or classes like: SysStringLen, CComBSTR, SysAllocString, etc.
CComBSTR can even convert it to an array. I didn't test but I believe the null characters would be preserved.
Once you use a null terminated string function then the null character will be interpreted as the end of the string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, you're right, null characters would be preserved but the problem is when passing the string to any C function-

Comment: @cdonts: That's a problem with the C function. Refactor it to accept `BSTR` if you have to deal with '\0' being valid character.